# Closing the window and appending text node to a button

Tags: javascript

```
function close_w() {
    //close the window
}
function imgopen(image) {
    var newWindow=window.open("", "_blank", "width=450, height=400");
    var newButton=newWindow.document.createElement("button");
    var textNode=newWindow.document.createTextNode("Close");
    newButton.setAttribute("style", "text-align: center; width: 30%; height: 30px; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 35%; border: none; color: #FFF; background-color: #DC143C");
    newButton.setAttribute("onclick", "close_w()");
    newWindow.document.newButton.appendChild(textNode); // Line Marker
    newWindow.document.body.appendChild(newButton);
}
```

I want to put a button in a popup, but appending textNode to newButton does not work and even the button does not show. If I delete the line marked, only the button shows.

And I also want to make the popup close when the button is clicked, but I cannot imagine how to do that. What functions can I use to make close_W()?

This is a kind of assignment: I cannot use jQuery here.

I am weak at JS. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like other buttons, you need to set the value of `newButton` to get the text added to it. Something like `newButton.setAttribute("value", "Close Window");`. This example would be for a button in an `input`. If you were to use the `<button></button>` tag, I would suggest you use `newButton.innerHTML = "Close Window";` as that should set the text to "Close Window".

Comment: I saw some answers here saying making text node and appending it to the button will work. Is there a way to use that way? I know innerhtml will work, but just curious.

Comment: I am not sure how you would be able to use text node and appending it to a button. Using text node is preferable when adding text to tags such as `<p></p>`, but I have never tried to use it on buttons. It is likely possible but I don't know how you could do it and I would nonetheless, not suggest it.